# Monitoring of multiple files, starting from Windows boot

Tags: c#, windows, file, notifications

I'm trying to make a program for sort of "tagging" (in my case they are not tags actually) Windows files, putting descriptions etc. Language: C#. I need somewhat of a guideline for a way to monitor all these "tagged" files, to get notifications in case they're renamed,moved,deleted. And I want to monitor them from the time Windows boots til the moment the user shuts the PC down.
I've checked this FileSystemWatcher class, but still:

- Is it a good idea to make a separate instance of this class for every file I want to follow?
- Is it actually a Windows Service that I should make for this functionality ?

I'll be more than happy to get any advice on what my approach is best to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `FileSystemWatcher` to watch a directory (and, potentially, subdirectories). It will be notified of changes to all files in the watched directories. You can then filter for the individual files you want to watch.

I would suggest one `FileSystemWatcher` for each top-level directory you want to watch. So if you're watching:

```
/dir1
/dir1/subdir
/dir1/subdir/sub-subdir
/dir2
```

Then you'd have two `FileSystemWatcher` components: one for `dir1`, and one for `dir2`

A Windows service is a good selection for this tool. Another good selection would be a console application that is run at startup as a scheduled task. The scheduled task has the benefit of letting you start and stop it more easily. Which might be the way you want to go for initial development. It's pretty easy to convert a console application to a service.

Comment: With that being said is it a good idea to have a FSW for each of the volumes on the computer ?

Comment: @IlianVasilevKulishev: You have to balance the number of FSW instances with the expected load. You probably don't want to watch the entire volume if some directory is getting hundreds of new or changed files every minute. You're better off in that case making separate FSW components for the directories you're interested in so that it doesn't get all those extraneous notifications of files that you don't care about.