# Windows Service + Windows Forms application. One database. Advice on concurrency

Tags: c#, database, winforms, concurrency, windows-services

I have SQL Server database with information for files - I'm talking about custom properties. These are categories and description for each file.

The Windows Forms application is for the user. But I will also make a Windows Service that will track any changes with the files. If a change happens(renamed,moved,deleted) the service has to update that same database accordingly. And I think it should do it right away, without any delay.

Now this is going to be my first time making WS plus the first time I will have to handle concurrency (theoretically I know about threads and so on).

So:

- First of all, is it OK if one process is updating a database another process may be using at the same time? Do you need to handle that situation on the first place? (Probably, fx in our daily "user lives" we can't modify a file when it's being used by another process)
- Is the idea these two to share one data source good ?
- If it is, then how to handle the concurrency ? I can use WCF for the messages between the two, but then does the solution have something to do with WCF ? Because I'm going to use this for the first time as well :D.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance for the time !

Comment: Do you hear about [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MS SQL is transactional there will be no big deal. You just have to watch out for data wich might be read and updated by one process - there it can be neccessary to use a Transaction scope (that's a .NET Class ;)).

From the Software architectural Point of view you should conside using a three-tier and not a two-tier application:

**Two Tier**:
Essentially your System with the persistance-layer (DB) communicating with the Clients directly

**Three Tier**:
Persistance-Layer <--> Logic-Layer (e.g. a WCF-Service handling the app logic) <--> Clients (Service and Forms - triggering app logic and showing results)

Comment: I already knew that if there's no problem with the concurrency (as it turned out) this three tier architecture is probably the way to go. But since I will mess with WCF for the first time, more questions are yet to arise related to that. I will address them in another topic. Or can I put them here? Is it going to be considered an off topic ?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to concurrency it's going to be really straight forward. The MSSQL database engine handles just about all of it (e.g. locking and sharing). Further, if you leverage the SqlCommandBuilder to build your statements, the statements will automatically use optimistic concurrency.

As for the Windows service and how it gets notified, use a FileSystemWatcher, it going to be more efficient and you won't be published some service port on the local box.

I'd normally give you some good code examples but I'm answering this from my phone.

Comment: Yes, FSWatcher. I already have a topic on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764439/monitoring-of-multiple-files-starting-from-windows-boot But still, if there's something you might add to it, you are welcomed to do it :) Thanks.