# Advice on layered architecture (Win Forms + WinService; WCF; LINQ to SQL)

Tags: winforms, wcf, linq-to-sql, architecture, windows-services

I'll try to explain as briefly as possible:

**C#.Windows application for categories and descriptions of files.**

**Windows Forms** - for the user

**A library I want to be saved for future usage** - I got nice algorithms for tasks with XML,Files,strings. In this case they are to serve the WF, but i don't want to keep them in the Form classes. I want to have them as a separate library with namespaces and classes in it. But I don't know what type of project or addition to the whole VS "Solution" that has to be.

**Windows Service** - get notifications on file changes and updates the same db the WF is using.

**LINQ to SQL** - for the data access

**WCF** - I am just throwing that here, because it seems that I need to use it(answer from a previous related topic) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15998122/1356685

SO...yeah...architecture, architecture. Any guideline for a good architecture in my case is welcomed. Now I know in these conversations people start throwing terms like: "business logic","persistence layer","model layer" and what not. However I don't quite understand them, so please be specific.

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: Keep in mind that `Linq To SQL` has been deprecated by Microsoft in favor of `Entity Framework`. And that winforms is a really really antiquated technology, also left behind in favor of much more elegant, scalable, faster, and customizable XAML-based UI frameworks (such as WPF or WinRT). So, before starting your project, I would suggest you consider the reasons why you're using these old technologies to begin with.

Comment: linq to sql - it's sql server db, and it's just one table btw. EF is nice, but at this point, it's too powerful and full of capabilities. I'll learn it in the future.
winforms - wpf is nice with the declarative code and what not, but my project is not about stunning visuals to start with, and just like EF I'll learn it later.

Comment: WPF is not (only) about stunning visuals... It's a much better UI framework with built-in support for things such as `DataBinding` (real Databinding) which simplify a LOT the code and helps keep your code really clean. It also saves a lot of time by not having to write a ton of boilerplate code in order to pass data between Model and UI.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a pretty extensive [application architecture guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650706.aspx) and their [patterns and practices website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921345.aspx) has a lot of information and code samples showing you how to structure applications.

As for your 'library to be saved for future usage'... you can create a [C# Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229042%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) project and add it as a Reference in whatever applications you'd like to use it in.

Comment: Ye I spotted the guide,but didn't want to learn everything.In order to save time (just for now!) I just wanted a piece of experience from somebody. 
As for the library, ok I'll do that. Thanks !

Comment: With reference to @Grumbler85's answer in your [referenced link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15998122/1356685): "Three Tier: Persistance-Layer <--> Logic-Layer (e.g. a WCF-Service handling the app logic) <--> Clients (Service and Forms - triggering app logic and showing results)". To apply that to your listed parts in the OP, you'll probably want to package each layer into a separate project -- Persistence (your Linq to SQL classes), Logic (your WCF svc), and then your Presentation layer, or your Forms App (as a Forms application project).

Comment: Where do you see the Windows Service here ?
What is going to host the WCF service ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're creating a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx), you'll want to create that as a separate project. It will be its own little program.